# Python Algorithm 3.2 - Help me with the errors please.?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

Here is my coding:

```
def main():
    actualValued()
    assessed_value()
    printResult()

def actualValued():
    global assessed_value
    global property_tax
    assessed_value = 0.6 * actualValue
    property_tax = assessed_value/100*0.64

def printResult():
    print( "For a property valued at"), actualValued
    print( "The assessed value is"), asessed_value
    print( "The property tax is"), property_tax

actualValue = None
assessed_value = None
property_tax = None

main()
```

The Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Documents and Settings/Desktop/property tax.py", line 21, in <module>
main()

File "C:/Documents and Settings/Desktop/property tax.py", line 2, in main
actualValued()

File "C:/Documents and Settings/Desktop/property tax.py", line 9, in actualValued
assessed_value = 0.6 * actualValue

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
>>>
```

What I am trying to do:

Enter assessed value 10000.0
For a property valued at $10,000.00
The assessed value is $6,000.00
And the tax is $38.40

Property Tax: A county collects property taxes on the assessment value of property, which is 60 percent of the property's actual value. For example, if an acre of land is valued at $10,000, its assessment value is $6,000. The property tax is then 64cents for each $100 of the assessment value. The tax for the acre assessed at $6,000 will be $38.40.

I need the actual value for the piece of property and the display of the assessment value and property tax.

Functions I need to use:

- one to get the input from the user
- one to calculate all values
- one to output the results
- and a main function to call the three other functions

Answer (score 2):

You set actualValue=None and then you try to use it in functions but a) You don't ever assign it and b) before you assign it within a function you will have to call global actualValue as you did with the other variables.  You don't need to use global if you are only reading as was pointed out by @cdhowie

Since actualValue is of Nonetype you cannot multiply it by another number.  That is your error.

You can do 1 of 3 things.

1) where you have actualValue=None  Change it to actualValue=10000.

2) set actualValue in main as follows:

```
def main():
    global actualValue
    actualValue = 10000
    ...
```

3) parameterize your functions as suggested by another answer.

Comment: It's fine that he doesn't use `global` -- he only reads from the variable and does not write to it.  `global` is only important when trying to *write* to variables in a parent scope.

Comment: true, except he needs to write to it somewhere.  I'll edit the post.

Comment: Yes, he does -- that's the reason that I upvoted your answer.  But the comment about `global` is incorrect and is just a red herring.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to rewrite your code so that it uses parameters and return values instead of global variables.

```
def actualValued(actualValue):
    assessed_value = 0.6 * actualValue
    property_tax = assessed_value/100*0.64
    return assessed_value, property_tax

# get your actual value from user input e.g.
value = raw_input('Give actual value: ')
value = float(value)
assessed, tax = actualValued(value)

print( "For a property valued at"), valued
print( "The assessed value is"), asessed
print( "The property tax is"), tax
```